# Getting an “Boot Device Not Found (3F0)” error on HP ZBook 15 G2

Tags: windows, windows-10

Attempting to turn on computer and get this error:

> “Boot Device Not Found (3F0)”

I run diagnostic test and hard drive test quick and extended pass will not boot with a USB boot drive.

Any suggestions on how to deal with this?

Comment: What does the hard drive quick test have to do with a USB boot?  Have you tried this USB boot medium in another computer?

Comment: Well let’s see I have since I wrote this question. I have determined the sad drive I have is bad so when I get a replacement for that,I’ll see what happens. But it has nothing to do with the usb.

Comment: Bummer!  Sorry to hear that.  I hope it all goes well when you get the new drive.

Answer (score 0):

Try to check if your HDD is correct or BIOS boot order is correct.
Open BIOS by pressing F12, F10, Esc, DEL , or whatsoever works for you, then move to boot section, and then check if your HardDisk is present and listed in any of the boot priorities, and also, its name is diaplayed. If not, then it means your HDD is not read by the BIOS.
Check if HDD is correctly connected and all wirings are correct, in place and tight.
Start your PC again, and check if uour HDD wheel is spinning by feeling its vibration. If that is correct, then try Bios again, if now, if you see your HDD there, then try booting, but if not, then it might be possible that your HDD is corrupt and gone, or your SATA cable is wrong.